# Postgresql foreign tables exists clause

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, foreign-data-wrapper

I'm running two different postgres 9.3 instances (one for production, one for development/testing). I want to copy a subset of a table in production into development.

Let's say then that the table I want to copy is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE users (user_id varchar PRIMARY KEY, other_stuff varchar);
```

and the subset I want to copy is all the users who have user_id in a cached table (on production), which is a much smaller table than the users table

```
CREATE TABLE user_id_subset (user_id varchar PRIMARY KEY);
```

I've set up some foreign tables on my development db to access these two tables (named foreign_users, and foreign_user_id_subset respectively), and I want to do a query like:

```
INSERT INTO development_users (user_id, other_stuff) 
    SELECT user_id, other_stuff FROM foreign_users f
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM foreign_user_id_subset ss 
        WHERE ss.user_id=f.user_id)
```

This query works, but I'm worried about performance. The result of an explain gives me something like this:

```
'Insert on development_users (cost=262.01..284.09 rows=138 width=272)'
'  ->  Hash Join  (cost=262.01..284.09 rows=138 width=272)'
'        Hash Cond: ((f.user_id)::text = (cache.user_id)::text)'
'        ->  Foreign Scan on foreign_users f  (cost=100.00..118.28 rows=276 width=272)'
'        ->  Hash  (cost=159.52..159.52 rows=200 width=32)'
'              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=157.52..159.52 rows=200 width=32)'
'                    ->  Foreign Scan on foreign_user_id_subset  (cost=100.00..153.86 rows=1462 width=32)'
```

What I *think* is happening is that my development db sends the request to my production db, which creates the temp hash of foreign_user_id_subset (user_id_subset on production) and does the hash check on production. This way, the only thing that gets sent across the wire (between the databases) is the initial request, and then the result of the select query. Is this true?

An alternative idea would be to create a 'temp' (can't be a true TEMP table b/c I need a foreign table) of the result of this request on my production database, and then build a foreign table and just do a SELECT * from development on the foreign table.

(It should be noted that my production database is a much pricier/performant RDS instance than my development database)

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

I implemented the alternative idea described above: generating the table in production containing only the results of the EXISTS query, and then created a foreign table in development to reference that table. Then to create the subset table, I just did an 'INSERT INTO ...SELECT * FROM ...'.

The timing was dramatically faster using this than the original method posted.

Time to create table on production:
`Total runtime: 204.838 ms`

Time to insert into development database: `Total runtime: 1564.444 ms`

And to do the original method:
it's unacceptably slow, taking > 10 minutes to achieve the same result as above (I didn't even wait for the explain analyze to finish)

I don't know a better way to determine lower-level instructions past what the planner provides, but I'm lead to believe that the original method performs a sequential scan (made by repeatedly scanning chunks of the foreign table) and performs the hash comparison on the development database.